# Eigenvalues different in R and scipy

Tags: python, r, matrix

How come that I get different eigenvalues for Python

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(np.array([[1,1],[1,1]]))

>>> array([0., 2.])
```

than I get for the same matrix in R

```
> eigen(Inverse(matrix(c(1,1,1,1), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)))
eigen() decomposition
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1]  0.1666667 -0.2500000

$vectors
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.7071068  0.7071068
[2,] 0.7071068 -0.7071068
```

Even if the scaling of the eigenvectors/eigenvalues is different - the presented values suggest different definity of the matrices...

Comment: For the R users, it might be useful to include where the `Inverse` function comes from.

Comment: (Particularly since when I run the R code without `Inverse` I get the same eigenvalues as the Python code.)

Comment: as @joran says, why using the Inverse function? 1.- Such a matrix doesnt have inverse and 2.- you are not comparing the same thing in R and Python

Comment: @joran: `Inverse` comes from the package "matlib"

Comment: @Ismor: See comment.